# How to proxy a shell process in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I'm creating a script to wrap jdb (java debugger).  I essentially want to wrap this process and proxy the user interaction.  So I want it to:

- start jdb from my script
- send the output of jdb to stdout
- pause and wait for input when jdb does
- when the user enters commands, pass it to jdb

At the moment I really want a pass thru to jdb.  The reason for this is to initialize the process with specific parameters and potentially add more commands in the future.

**Update:**
Here's the shell of what ended up working for me using expect:

```
PTY.spawn("jdb -attach 1234") do |read,write,pid|
  write.sync = true

  while (true) do
    read.expect(/\r\r\n> /) do |s|
      s = s[0].split(/\r\r\n/)
      s.pop # get rid of prompt                                                                                              

      s.each { |line| puts line }

      print '> '
      STDOUT.flush

      write.print(STDIN.gets)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby standard library includes `expect`, which is designed for just this type of problem. See [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/pty/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-expect) for more information.

Comment: The links aren't valid any more.

Comment: Thanks; I removed the sample links. If you find any current sites with example usage please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Open3.popen3()`. e.g.:

```
 Open3.popen3("jdb args") { |stdin, stdout, stderr|
     # stdin = jdb's input stream
     # stdout = jdb's output stream
     # stderr = jdb's stderr stream
     threads = []
     threads << Thread.new(stderr) do |terr|
         while (line = terr.gets)
            puts "stderr: #{line}"
         end
     end
     threads << Thread.new(stdout) do |terr|
         while (line = terr.gets)
            puts "stdout: #{line}"
         end
     end
     stdin.puts "blah"
     threads.each{|t| t.join()} #in order to cleanup when you're done.
 }
```

I've given you examples for threads, but you of course want to be responsive to what jdb is doing. The above is merely a skeleton for how you open the process and handle communication with it.