# How to execute interactive shell program on a remote host from ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to execute an interactive shell program on a remote host from another ruby program. For the sake of simplicity let's suppose that the program I want to execute is something like this:

```rb
puts "Give me a number:"
number = gets.chomp()
puts "You gave me #{number}"
```

The approach that most successful has been so far is using the one I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839075/how-to-proxy-a-shell-process-in-ruby). It is this one:

```rb
require 'open3'
Open3.popen3("ssh -tt root@remote 'ruby numbers.rb'") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    # stdin  = input stream
    # stdout = output stream
    # stderr = stderr stream
    threads = []
    threads << Thread.new(stderr) do |terr|
        while (line = terr.gets)
          puts "stderr: #{line}"
        end
    end
    threads << Thread.new(stdout) do |terr|
        while (line = terr.gets)
          puts "stdout: #{line}"
        end
    end

    sleep(2)
    puts "Give me an answer: "
    answer = gets.chomp()
    stdin.puts answer


    threads.each{|t| t.join()} #in order to cleanup when you're done.
end
```

The problem is that this is not "interactive" enough to me, and the program that I would like to execute (not the simple numbers.rb) has a lot more of input / output. You can think of it as an `apt-get install` that will ask you for some input to solve some problems.
I have read about net::ssh and pty, but couldn't see if they were going to be the (easy/elegant) solution I am looking for.

The ideal solution will be to make it in such a way that the user does not realize that the IO is being done on a remote host: the stdin goes to the remote host stdin, the stdout from the remote host comes to me and I show it.

If you have any ideas I could try I will be happy to hear them. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Net::SSH?

Comment: I have seen the on_data method to get the output. The problem is that I don't want to execute a command and get its output. I want to execute a command, show its output, get the input from the user, show more output, etc.
I don't see how to do that with net::ssh (or the others).

Comment: Re: *The ideal solution will be to make it in such a way that the user does not realize that the IO is being done on a remote host: the stdin goes to the remote host stdin, the stdout from the remote host comes to me and I show it.*   The way to achieve that is `ssh user@remote program`. No local Ruby program to get in the way of the transparency. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
require "readline"
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("ssh -tt root@remote 'ruby numbers.rb'") do |i, o, e, th|


  Thread.new {
    while !i.closed? do
      input =Readline.readline("", true).strip 
      i.puts input
    end
  }

  t_err = Thread.new {
    while !e.eof?  do
      putc e.readchar
    end
  }

  t_out = Thread.new {
    while !o.eof?  do
      putc o.readchar
    end
  }

  Process::waitpid(th.pid) rescue nil 
  # "rescue nil" is there in case process already ended.

  t_err.join
  t_out.join

end
```

I got it working, but don't ask me why it works. It was mainly trial/error.

Alternatives:

- Using Net::SSH, you need to use :on_process and a Thread: [ruby net/ssh channel dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942279/ruby-net-ssh-channel-dies) Don't forget to add `session.loop(0.1)`. More info at the link. The Thread/:on_process idea inspired me to write a gem for my own use: https://github.com/da99/Chee/blob/master/lib/Chee.rb
- If the last call in your Ruby program is SSH, then you can `exec ssh -tt root@remote 'ruby numbers.rb'`. But, if you still want interactivity between `User<->Ruby<->SSH`, then the previous alternative is the best.

Comment: This is such a useful piece of code. Thanks for creating and sharing this.

Comment: This doesn't really work to the extent needed to be able to fully interact with the shell. For example, some commands may require vi(m) to open and allow a document to be edited, and this wouldn't handle that. Though it would be nice if Ruby could handle it, I think many times it is safer just to write shell scripts in bash if you will require that level of interactivity.